# Tastypie PUT : partial update on all objects in a resource

Tags: tastypie

I have a django model like this, (BTW: I am using Tastypie)

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey('users.User')
  stocks = models.ManyToManyField('Stock')
  equityboss = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
  last_watched =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  order = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
```

I want to update **order** field alone for all the objects in watchlist model.

I tried by sending PUT request, it erased all my records. I didn't get any error.
This is the data I send via PUT request

```
{'objects': [{'resource_uri': '/api/eboss/watchlist/2/', 'id': u'2', 'order': 0}, {'resource_uri': '/api/eboss/watchlist/1/', 'id': u'1', 'order': 1}]}
```

Please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Look into HTTP PATCH ([the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)) - it's supported by Tastypie ([their docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#partially-updating-an-existing-resource-patch)) and allows you to partially update a resource.

It looks like you will need to make individual PATCHes to each resource, however, as there is no mention of PATCHing a list in the same way you can PUT a new copy of the list.

Comment: No need for individual patches. I have changed the PUT request as PATCH request, it is working now.